# Is it, "otherwise directed" vs. "directed otherwise"?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, word-order, participles

I've seen conflicting usage of the two phrases, and I wonder which one is grammatically correct and why?

Following are example sentence:

> 1. Do something unless directed otherwise.
> 2. Do something unless otherwise directed.

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case, "otherwise directed" has become a standard idiomatic construction--but both are acceptable.

Contrast this with:

```
Do something unless you are told otherwise.

Do something unless you are otherwise told.
```

Here, the former sentence still sounds okay, but the latter sentence sounds unnatural.