# "Unless instructed to do so" vs "Unless instructed otherwise" preferred usage

Tags: negation, phrase-requests, unless

I want to give a short but clear instruction like:

```
 1. Please do NOT perform X unless instructed to do so.
 2. Please do NOT perform X unless instructed otherwise.
```

Which one would be a better option considering popularity and clarity for any kind of audience? Are sentences correct? Are there better options?

Comment: Your second sentence is somewhat unusual. Although i can understand it, it's a kind of triple negative. In terms of construction, it would make more sense to read *please (DO) perform X unless instructed otherwise* (although that meaning is different) or *please avoid doing X until instructed otherwise* (which also has a slightly different meaning).

Comment: I agree with Jason Bassford. The first version is simpler and less likely to be misinterpreted.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Now I see a clear difference. Just as a side note: according to this [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/5888/323744) my second sentence should be written as `Please do NOT perform X unless otherwise instructed`  

Comment: @CamelCamelius Actually, in that answer it's the sentence with *otherwise* at the end (as yours) that is indicated as preferred. However, not only is that just stylistic, but your particular construction isn't the same. The repeated use of negatives aside, the location of your *otherwise* is fine.